# Silverlight What should a worker thread do after finish work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

So here is my problem with my Windows Phone application.

I have Page 1 that can navigate to Page 2. In Page 2 `OnNavigateTo` I make a async call.

This seems ok the first time I run the application, the async call creates a new worker thread and does work for me which is cool. 
But I realize that if I go back to Page 1 and re-invoke Page 2 the problem appears: Now I have a new worker thread from the async call while the old one was not terminated. So there is a race between the two worker threads and cause a problem to my application. 
I don't have direct control to the threads since they are implicitly created by async methods.

So in this case, anyone has suggestion on how to deal with it or is there a common pattern of dealing with this issue?

Comment: what is the error, show some code please

Comment: there are many types of async calls, but they tend to be pairs, a "begin" type call and an "end" call, and a common pattern is that the end call receives an IAsyncResult object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're issuing the async request.  If you're using say, `WebClient` to do something like `DownloadStringAsync` you'll see that your `WebClient` instance has a method `CancelAsync` that will set the cancelled property in your `Completed` event handler to `true`. Just call `CancelAsync` when you leave your page and test for this in your handler and you should be good.

```
// in some button handler or whereever
webClient.DownloadStringAsync("http://url.com")

void OnLeavePage(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  webClient.CancelAsync();
}

void OnCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Cancelled) {
    return;
  }

  // do your handling
}
```

If you don't have `CancelAsync` you can pass in a `UserState` object that has a `Cancelled` property to emulate the behaviour (set it to true when you leave and test in your handler).